# confused about testing $promise

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm testing out a controller which has a method that returns a json object from my server.  I'm really confused on how to make expectations on what my method is returning.

I need to do some cleaning up of my scope based on the results.

What I'm trying to accomplish is Call search() -> see what data is getting returned -> and if the length==0 -> make sure my scope has certain values removed.  How can I check what my method has returned?

```
$scope.clearIds = function(){  
     //clean out data I don't need anymore
   }

   $scope.search = function(inputValue, modelname, action, field){
    modelname = modelname || 'companies';
    action = action || 'search';
    field = field || 'title';

    return apiResource.query({api_resource:modelname, api_action:action, api_column:field, api_value:inputValue}).$promise.then(function(response){
     if(response.data.length === 0){   
       $scope.clearIds();
     }
     else{
      return response.data;
    }
  });
  }

  describe('Controller - TypeaheadSearch', function () {

    // load the controller's module
    beforeEach(module('app'));

    var scope;
    var apiResource;
    var stateParams;
    var q;
    var deferred; 
    var rootScope;

    // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, $q) {

      apiResource = {
        query: function() {
          deferred = $q.defer();
          deferred.resolve('bar');
          return deferred.promise;
        }
      };
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      stateParams = {};
      q = $q;
      rootScope = $rootScope;
      $controller('TypeaheadSearch', {
        $scope: scope,
        $stateParams:stateParams,
        apiResource: apiResource,
      });
    }));

    it('Should call apiResource:query', function() {

      spyOn(apiResource, 'query').and.callThrough();
      scope.search();
      rootScope.$apply();
      expect(apiResource.query).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
```

Comment: More simpler you could just do `apiResource  = jasmine.CreateSpyObj('apiresource', ['query']);
          apiResource.query.and.returnValue($q.when(expectedQueryValue ));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a spy for $scope.clearIds() and then `expect(scope.clearIds).toHaveBeenCalled()`, and/or check that `clearIds()` has had the effect you want.

Next, resolve the fake promise with data that resembles what your code expects.
Do this in your (`it()`) test, so you can see how the code responds to different data (e.g. returning an array with something in it).

```
deferred.resolve({data: []});
```

Comment: Ok then my next question is how to not have to rewrite the whole beforeEach block just to change the resolved data that gets passed in?  Do I just nest it and duplicate the whole beforeEach block thing again?

Also I guess what I'm reading is - **It doesn't matter what data the return is sending back.  We already know that.  What IS important is what the code is doing with the fake data we're sending.** 

Right?

Comment: Why would you need to rewrite the whole beforeEach block? Just move that one "deferred.resolve()" line into your test.
Even if you did need to run all of the code again in your test, JS has these crazy things called functions that make code duplication unnecessary.

Comment: It does matter what your code does with the fake data, but if your code is checking the length of the array at `response.data`, and instead of any of that you give it a string, then how can you expect the test to be meaningful? Who told you the data doesn't matter?

Comment: The issue I'm running into now is when I do this it works in my controller but not in my test: apiResource.query().$promise.then()

When I use apiResource.query.then() it works in my test but not in my controller.  What's the deal?

Comment: Ah yes, query is that one odd function that returns promises a little differently to everything else. Do this in your test: `return {$promise: deferred.promise};`

Comment: Yup that did the trick.   So what about get?  Would I resolve that the same way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78449/discussion-between-justin-young-and-hankscorpio).